# On Negative AIC Values

Tags: aic

My question is related to the thread [Negative values for AIC in General Mixed Model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84076/negative-values-for-aic-in-general-mixed-model).  I often get negative AIC values from the software I use.  I notice it most when I'm doing time series.  But here is what I don't get.  When defining the AIC like

$$AIC = 2k-2\ln(L)$$

$L$, the likelihood, is a joint probability and to my understanding must be bound between 0 and 1.  Mathematically this implies the $AIC$ must be positive.  So I don't know what my software is giving me for the value labeled $AIC$.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What software do you use?  Could you give us a specific example that yields a negative AIC so we can check using our software and analyses?

Comment: Likelihoods *do not* need to be $\leq 1$, since densities can exceed 1. Indeed, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Likelihoods_for_continuous_distributions): "likelihood is only defined up to a multiplicative constant"; (only positive ones could make sense, though). Log-likelihoods only make sense when compared with other log likelihoods (the arbitrary shift must be the same for both, naturally).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$L$ is not a joint probability (joint cumulative probability density) but joint probability density. Since density only needs to be non-negative and is not bounded from above, $\operatorname{ln}(L)$ can be both positive and negative. Hence, $AIC$ can also be both positive and negative.

Comment: (+1) NB For a discrete response the likelihood will be a joint probability, provided you don't drop any constant factor necessary to keep it so.

Comment: Thanks for the help...Should have known this one, but doing so much probit/logit lately I forgot the greater realm of MLE.