# Can I compare a negative AIC with a positive AIC?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, aic

The original model gives me an AIC of 75.43 and the Box-Cox transformed model gives me -189.2013. Does this me the Box-Cox transformed model is a much better model here?

Comment: Did you include the geometric mean as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Definition?  Only then are the AIC-values compareable.

Comment: fit = lm(mor^0.1818182~x) My model ended up giving me a lambda of 0.1818182.

Comment: You need to use the complete formula in wikipedia, otherwise you're comparing the likelihood of a model specifying the distribution of `mor` with a model specifying the distribution of `mor^0.1818`.  These are not compareable.  Using the complete formula, you get comparaable likelihoods and you'll probably see a much smaller difference in log likelihoods and AICs.

Comment: I followed the steps here: http://www.yimizhao.com/single-post/2015/04/10/BoxCox-Transformations-for-Linear-Models-1

Comment: Subtracting one and dividing by $\lambda \text{GM}^{\lambda-1}$ is only a linear transformation so ommiting this (as in the example you link to) does not affect R-square values.  To compare maximum log-likelihoods and AICs, however, you need to use the complete formula in wikipedia.

Comment: So if I find my lambda = 0.1818182 ...my new linear regression becomes fit = lm(mor^0.1818182~x) under the Box-Cox transformation.

Comment: Instead of `mor^.18` you need to use `(mor^.18-1)/(.18*exp(mean(log(mor)))^(.18-1))` as your response.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, so the website did not do all this transformation, so my regression becomes lm((mor^.18-1)/(.18*exp(mean(log(mor)))^(.18-1))~x)?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Umm..this guys on the website has md_best<-lm(I(O3^lambda)~temp+humidity+ibh,data=ozone)...

Comment: ? not sure what this last comment means ?  BTW, negative vs positive is a red herring, e.g see http://emdbolker.wikidot.com/faq

Comment: From R, md_best<-lm(I(O3^lambda)~temp+humidity+ibh,data=ozone). It appears this guy didn't do something like (mor^.18-1)/(.18*exp(mean(log(mor)))^(.18-1) in the linear regression.

Comment: Some miracle happened...my AIC for all models are positive now!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking: Yes, you can compare negative and positive values of AIC, it can happen. There is no reason why AIC should be exclusively non-negative; this has been covered already by some posts [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134840) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84076).

Having said that, you should not compare AIC values from models with different response values. In that case the (log-) likelihoods calculated correspond to variables from different scales so their comparison can be totally misleading; I discuss this a bit with a bit more detail [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/).